# Difference between sum and mean in .backward() in calculating the loss and backpropagated through the network

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I know we are converting the tensor in scaler than applying backward(), but when to sum and when to mean?

```
some_loss_function.sum().backward()
-OR-
some_loss_function.mean().backward()
```

Comment: `mean = sum / batch_size`. The result is the same as multiplying or dividing the learning rate by `batch_size`. There is no difference than that. Usually, you do not want the loss to change as you change the batch size, so mean is recommended. You may possibly use sum when you implement your own loss algorism, as this forced-division behavior can be disturbing.

Comment: *"The result is the same as multiplying or dividing the learning rate by batch_size. There is no difference than that"*. That is not true, this all depends on the type of optimization algorithm used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some Research I found the difference hope that will help you out:

`some_loss_function.sum().backward()` calculates the sum of all the loss values across the batch and then performs backpropagation based on that sum. This means that each element of the batch contributes equally to the loss, regardless of its value. This can be useful in some scenarios, such as when you want to prioritize rare events that have a small number of occurrences in the batch.

`some_loss_function.mean().backward()` calculates the mean of all the loss values across the batch and then performs backpropagation based on that mean. This means that each element of the batch contributes equally to the loss, but the contribution is weighted by its value. This can be useful in scenarios where you want to prioritize elements of the batch that have a higher loss value, or when you want to ensure that the gradients are scaled appropriately.

Comment: Please don't dump ChatGPT output into the site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no canonical answer to your question. Essentially what you're asking is should I average or sum my loss, as readers we have no knowledge of your problem and what this loss function corresponds to. It all depends on your use case.

Generally though, you would average over summation because you often don't wish the loss value to scale with the dimensionality of the output. Indeed high dimensionality of your output would lead to a higher value to your loss than a summation which is meant to be constant w.r.t. the dimensions of your output tensor. If you sum your loss you will end up scaling your loss value and the gradients that are inferred from it uncontrollably.